GridSearch hyperparameter tuning with KerasClassifier : ValueError: Sequential model 'sequential' has no defined outputs yet
I am try to do an hyperparameter tuning for an LSTM model using GridSearch and KerasClassifier.
It's a multiclass classification problem of a text dataset.
I saw in the documentation that n_outputs_expected_ should be set to the number of expected classes.
I do not understand what the issue is.
!pip install scikeras
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from scikeras.wrappers import KerasClassifier

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Embedding, LSTM, Dense, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

def create_model(units, dropout, optimizer):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Embedding(5000, 128, input_length=100))
    model.add(LSTM(units))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout))
    model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer,metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

param_grid = {
    'model__units': [50, 100, 150],
    'model__dropout': [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4],
    'model__optimizer': ['adam', 'rmsprop'],
    'epochs': [10, 20, 30],
    'batch_size': [32, 64, 128]
}


grid_search_model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, n_outputs_expected_ = 3, error_score='raise')
grid_search_model = GridSearchCV(estimator=grid_search_model, param_grid=param_grid, cv=3)
grid_result = grid_search_model.fit(X_train_tf, label_encoded_y_train)


/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/scikeras/wrappers.py:925: UserWarning: ``build_fn`` will be renamed to ``model`` in a future release, at which point use of ``build_fn`` will raise an Error instead.
  X, y = self._initialize(X, y)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/layers/core/embedding.py:90: UserWarning: Argument `input_length` is deprecated. Just remove it.
  warnings.warn(
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-154-d57ef5578357> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 grid_result = grid_search_model.fit(X_train_tf, label_encoded_y_train)

13 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/models/sequential.py in outputs(self)
    290         if self._functional:
    291             return self._functional.outputs
--> 292         raise ValueError(
    293             f"Sequential model '{self.name}' has no defined outputs yet."
    294         )

ValueError: Sequential model 'sequential_2595' has no defined outputs yet.


I modified the code by adding an input layer instead of passing the input
directly to the embedding layer, and I removed the error score argument from
the KerasClassifier, as it doesn't expect that argument. These changes made
the code work successfully.Please refer to this gist,let me if you are still facing issue.
